# Mutiple varaibles in while loop of bash scripting

Tags: bash

Suppose i have the below curl where i will be reading two of the varaibles from a file.how can we accomodate both the varaibles in a single while loop

```
while read p; do
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'HTTP_X_MERCHANT_CODE: STA' --header 'AK-Client-IP: 135.71.173.56' --header 'Authorization: Basic qwrewrereererweer'  -d '{
    "request_details": [
        {
            "id": "$p",  #first dynamic varaible which will be fetched from the file file.txt
            "id_id": "$q",  #second dynamic varaible to be fetched from the file file.txt
            "reason": "Pickup reattempts exhausted"
        }
    ]
}' api.stack.com/ask
done<file.txt
```

file.tx will have two columns from which the dynamic variables whill be fetched to the above curl. Pls let me know how can we accomodate both the variable in the above while loop

i will need bit of a help regarding the same

Comment: soo `while read p q; do` ?

Comment: Your current `curl` command won't work. `$p` and `$q` won't be expanded inside the single quotes defining the argument to `-d`. You should use something like `jq` to construct the JSON payload from the values of `p` and `q`.

Comment: You can get your `curl` command working with a `here document` or escaping the quotes on the right places (combined with `read -r p q`), but looking at a `jq` solution is IMHO the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll want to use a tool like `jq` to construct the payload anyway, you should let `jq` parse the file instead of using the shell.

```
filter='split(" ") |
  { request_details: [
       {
          id: .[0],
          id_id: .[1],
          reason: "Pickup reattempts exhausted"
       }
    ]
  }'

jq -cR "$filter" file.txt | 
  while IFS= read -r payload; do
    curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                 --header 'Accept: application/json' \
                 --header 'HTTP_X_MERCHANT_CODE: STA' \
                 --header 'AK-Client-IP: 135.71.173.56' \
                 --header 'Authorization: Basic qwrewrereererweer' \
         -d "$payload"
  done
```

The `-c` option to `jq` ensures the entire output appears on one line: `curl` doesn't need a pretty-printed JSON value.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. i didnt got the use of varaible payload here

Comment: It's just the single-line JSON object read from the output of `jq`.

Comment: Run the `jq` command shown to see what the output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

`read` accepts multiple target variable names.  The last one receives all the content not yet read from the line.  So `read p` reads the whole line, `read p q` would read the first token (separated by whitespace) into `p` and the rest into `q`, and `read p q r` would read the first two tokens into `p` and `q` and any remaining junk into `r` (for example if you want to support comments or extra tokens in `file.txt`).